# Swapping pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing

```
# include <stdio.h>
void mystery (int *ptra, int *ptrb) {  
     int *temp; 
     temp = ptrb;  
     ptrb =ptra; 
     ptra = temp; 
} 
int main () { 
    int a = 2016, b=0, c= 4, d = 42; 
    mystery (&a, &b);
    if (a < c) 
          mystery (&c, &a); 
    mystery (&a, &d); 
    print f("%d\n", a); 
}
```

---

My attempt :

a and d are not swapped as the function mystery() doesn’t change values, but pointers which are local to the function.

> Can you explain in formal way, please. how works function `mystery`?

Comment: I was about to answer. But what does "in formal way" mean?

Comment: It doesn't do anything directly to your pointer values, it changes the copy of the pointer addresses for a moment, then when the function returns the values are restored.

Comment: The compiler will deduct that the function does nothing meaningful and optimize it away entirely.

Comment: And moreover you are not 'looking' at pointers, but you print the value of `a`. So what you expected that your function would have changed the variable address?

Comment: There are at least 2 duplicates for this "mystery".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a and d are not swapped as the function mystery() doesn’t change values, but pointers which are local to the function.

Yes, you are right. Function `mystery` is not swapping values. It is just swapping the pointer `ptra` and `ptrb` to location pointed by `ptrb` and `ptra` respectively.

```
                        a
                 +--------------+
                 |              |
ptra ----------> |    2016      |
                 |              |
                 +--------------+



                        b
                 +--------------+
                 |              |
ptrb ----------> |      0       |
                 |              |
                 +--------------+
```

After executing statements

```
temp = ptrb;  
ptrb =ptra; 
ptra = temp;    

                        a
                 +--------------+
                 |              |
ptra -----+      |    2016      |
        +------> |              |
        | |      +--------------+
        | |
        | |
        | |
        | |             b
        | |      +--------------+
        | |      |              |
ptrb ---+ +----> |      0       |
                 |              |
                 +--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: So, it's a valid change, rt?

Comment: Yes, but of no use in this case.

Comment: Please, can you explain second diagram in English?

Comment: I already explained it.

Answer (score 2):

In C, functions always pass by value.  So the pointer swapping you're doing has no effect outside the function because you're only changing local values.

Instead of swapping the pointers, you need to swap what they point to, i.e. you need to dereference them:

```
void mystery (int *ptra, int *ptrb) {  
     const int temp = *ptrb;
     *ptrb = *ptra; 
     *ptra = temp; 
}
```

Comment: Yes. But he is asking that whether he is correct or not about the reason  why `a` and `b` are not swapped.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your temporary needs to be an `int` **not** an `int*`:

`int temp = *ptrb;`

Then you need to *defererence* the pointers: `*ptrb = *ptra;` etc.

All you're currently doing is swapping the pointers in the function, and this will not be reflected in the function caller.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: So, why it's complied successfully?

Comment: Because swapping pointers is a perfectly legitimate thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The function `mystery()` does virtually nothing, and a compiler eliminated almost all of the function via optimization and left only `ret`.

[demo on Compiler Explorer](https://goo.gl/vSpK8U)

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note: mystery woks on copy of pointers being passeed to it. This has huge implications, most of them being you are not changing original pointers when you assign to pointers `ptra`, `ptrb` in your `mystery`.

```
void mystery (int *ptra, int *ptrb) {  
     int *temp; 
     temp = ptrb;  
     ptrb =ptra; 
     ptra = temp; 
}
```

Second thing: you are indeed assigning pointers to pointers, not values of what pointers points to. And given first mistake, the world outside of the `mystery` sees no changes at all.

Solution:

Dereference pointers to change values they are pointing to.

```
void
mystery (int *ptra, int *ptrb)
{  
    const int tmp;

    tmp = *ptrb;
    *ptrb = *ptra; 
    *ptra = tmp; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Comment: So, why it's complied successfully?

Comment: @RajUpadhyay The code is semantically correct, it just does not what you wanted.